# ExecutorService terminates unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading, exit, executorservice, amazon-kinesis

I have tried using different classes which implement the `ExecutorService` but all result in the same outcome: the executor exits early.

Here is my code:

```
public class StreamConsumer {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

final Environment environment;
final String streamName;
final String shardId;

public StreamConsumer(Environment environment, String streamName, String shardId) {
    this.environment = environment;
    this.streamName = streamName;
    this.shardId = shardId;
}

public void initialize() {
    try {
        final ListShardsRequest listShardsRequest = new ListShardsRequest().withStreamName(streamName);
        final ListShardsResult listShardsResult = environment.kinesis().listShards(listShardsRequest);
        final List<Shard> shards = listShardsResult.getShards();

        final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                .setDaemon(true)
                .setNameFormat(streamName + "-%d")
                .build();

        final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(shards.size(), threadFactory);
        shards.stream().map(ShardConsumer::new).forEach(consumer -> consumer.start(executor));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.warn("Unable to start Stream Consumer of {}", streamName, ex);
    }
}

private class ShardConsumer {
    private final String shardId;
    private String shardIterator;

    ShardConsumer(Shard shard) {
        this.shardId = shard.getShardId();
    }

    private String getShardIterator() {
        GetShardIteratorRequest shardIteratorRequest = new GetShardIteratorRequest()
                .withStreamName(streamName)
                .withShardId(shardId)
                .withShardIteratorType(ShardIteratorType.LATEST.name());

        return environment.kinesis().getShardIterator(shardIteratorRequest).getShardIterator();
    }

    void start(ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
        this.shardIterator = getShardIterator();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("Started consuming stream: {} with shardId: {}", streamName, shardId);
                    GetRecordsRequest request = new GetRecordsRequest().withShardIterator(shardIterator);
                    final GetRecordsResult records = environment.kinesis().getRecords(request);
                    UserRecord.deaggregate(records.getRecords()).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
                    shardIterator = records.getNextShardIterator();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                LOGGER.error("Problem consuming records from {} {}", streamName, shardId, e);
            }
        }, 0, 1_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

The code terminates at this line:

`final GetRecordsResult records = environment.kinesis().getRecords(request);`

I've also tried to create another `ExecutorService` which executes:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println(x)
}
```

It also terminates early and unexpectedly. I have no idea what the issue could be.

EDIT: I've found the issue. For whatever reason, the executor service doesn't like being run from a test class, I can create executor services that stay alive indefinitely from within the Main method. Does anybody know why this is? Or how it can be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Abruptly stops when an Exception occurs, try to check for errors

Comment: There is no exception, the test passes successfully which is the issue. The executor service for one should run until I terminate it and secondly all the methods within the `start()` method should execute.

Comment: Exceptions wont be reported inside a thread, try to debug inside the thread

Comment: I've tried that with no luck, no exceptions are thrown anywhere.

Comment: Put a `try … catch ( Exception e ) { … print stack trace … }` around the code of your task.

Comment: Just tried that, no exceptions are thrown nor caught.

Comment: You're using `setDaemon(true)`. I assume that's on threads. As per [javaDoc Thread.setDaemon​(boolean on)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) "The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.".

Comment: Using s`etDaemon(false)` doesn't change anything. It still terminates early.