# ExecutorService only works within Main method

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, threadpool, executorservice

I am trying to start and run a thread or ExecutorService from within a Test method annotated `@Test`, however, whenever I try to do so the `ExecutorService` terminates early. When I run the `ExecutorService` from the `Main` method it works as expected and stays alive until explicitly terminated.

I have an example code below.

```
public class TestConsumer {

    Runnable task = () -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running");
    };
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void runner() {
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'd say that's expected behavior, since any thread terminates, once its `run` method is done. Your `run` method simply prints something and then exits. Could you be more precise? As in what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem? You mention a test method, but I see no `@Test` annotation in the code you gave us. You also don't tell us which testing framework you're using, nor how you determined that the `ExecutorService` is terminating early.

Comment: Here is a link to my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659718/executorservice-terminates-unexpectedly

I'm trying to run a executor service that will constantly consume and deaggregate kinesis records as i'm trying to test for the existence of particular records within the stream.

Comment: @Slaw the test code just executes the `runner()` method. As for the framework i'm using it's JUnit 5. Also I determined it's terminating early because it only prints 2 lines before the test 'passes' and execution is complete.

Comment: All `runner()` does is schedule the task and then returns immediately. This would imply that your test method is only testing if the task is submitted successfully, no more, no less. What is it that you're actually trying to test?

Comment: Above i've written a comment about what i'm aiming to achieve. What I need is to be able to start an executor service that stays alive however, the executor service terminates as soon as it runs the task. The above example is quite simplified, so I provided a link to a prior question where I have written code for kinesis stream record consumption. In that example, the executes this line successfully:

`LOGGER.info("Started consuming stream: {} with shardId: {}", streamName, shardId);`

But that's as far as it gets.

Comment: How are you executing the test? IntelliJ? Gradle? Maven? Because, although I can't be 100% sure about this, it looks like Gradle calls `System.exit(...)` after the test task has completed. Not sure about other tools (i.e., IntelliJ, Maven, etc.). And since your test returns (successfully, though that doesn't matter here), the tests all finish and the JVM is terminated.